# Oracle select months out of a timeframe

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date

Being given a table t (id, from, to), where from and to are two dates the span over multiple years, i would like to do a select on that table, wich, for each timeframe in table t would return the month/year list within that timeframe.
E.G. the contents of table t would be:

```
id     from               to
1      01.10.2011         28.02.2012
2      01.06.2008         30.09.2008
```

the select statement should return id, month number in year, year :

```
1  10   2011
1  11   2011
1  12   2011
1  01   2012
1  02   2012
2  06   2008
2  07   2008
2  08   2008
2  09   2008
```

Any ideas how could i do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [row generator](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques):

```
 select 
    id,  
    ADD_MONTHS( "from", N.N ), 
    to_char( dt_column, 'mm' ) , 
    to_char( dt_column, 'yyyy' ) 
 from
  yourTable t 
 inner join
  (SELECT ROWNUM n
   FROM   ( SELECT 1 just_a_column
         FROM   dual
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365
  ) N
    on ADD_MONTHS( "from", N.N ) <= last_day( t."to" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest idea could be to create a small table that has a row with one date per month that spans your possible time frame.

You could join it where the dates are between your two needed.

Another option would be to look into the "connect by" and recursive queries.  Takes some learning though.